Image preview error in visual studio code
Error loading webview: Error: Could not register service worker: InvalidStateError: Failed to register a ServiceWorker: The document is in an invalid state.
I was trying to get the image preview in the vs code window, but unable to get that but got this error.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
